# Redundant PiServer and Database

Tags: database

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with PiServer from which 5 Raspberry Pi clients boot over network.
On the PiServer machine is also a database (mariaDB) that holds some information which is displayed on the PiServer clients. This works fine and is absolutely no heavy duty scenario. Every 5 seconds the clients are querying the database and one client is writing to the database every 5 seconds.

If one of the clients fails, in can replace it with some spare Raspberry Pi I have for that case. Switch the damaged one with the working one, it boots from the network and does his job.
But, what happens when my Raspberry Pi machine with the PiServer fails?

I can have a second Raspberry Pi with a identical installation of PiServer and identical setup. So if the PiServer fails I can swap the two machines like I do with the clients.

**But** how can i get a redundant database setup for this scenario?
I'm not tied to mariaDB, but a database which is easy to connect by php and rust would be nice.